# KML Example for Match Route Api

Tags: here-api

I'm struggling to submit a valid POST to

```
https://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json
```

my parameter are

```
"routemode":"truck",
"filetype":"KML",
"height":2.55,
"width":4,
"length":12,
"file":"LINESTRING(9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9201715 53.4410191,9.9243505 59.5565351,9.9201715 53.4410191)"
```

Response is:

```
"400 - {"faultCode":"888afd7b-db9f-44c9-b1cc-5787de1199a5","message":"Cannot process kml. Content is not allowed in prolog.","responseCode":"400 Bad Request"}"
```

What does a valid KML look like for posting to Match Route API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About KML Match route API supports.

```
KML: Either <Placemarks> with <Points> or <Placemarks> with <LineStrings> can be submitted. Folders with multiple traces are not supported.
```

Please see below thread for KML format.

[KML file format or minimum requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123721/kml-file-format-or-minimum-requirements)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I mixed up WKT with KML. Base64 decode the well-formed KML and submit it as a GET works fine.